# Cannot rename package - Some characters cannot be mapped using US-ASCII

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-kepler

I need to rename one of my packages in Eclipse but I have some problems. I've tried to rename it with classic way **right_click_on_package->refactor->rename** without success. Then I tried to to make a new package with desired name and have done this: **select_classses->right_click->move->choose_created package**. That was also unsuccessful.

Both times I received the following error:

[image]

What do you suggest I can do? Thanks!

Comment: What Text file encoding are you using for the source files (look at the Resource tab of the Properties)?

Comment: @greg-449. Thank you. Yes, it was a problem with encoding. I went to **Eclipse->Preferences->General->Workspace** and changed `Text file encoding` from `Default (US-ASCII)` to `Other: UTF-8`. Now everything works!